# Redirect HTTP -> HTTPS in DDEV using Apache

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, ddev

I need help to understand how to do HTTP redirects to HTTPS when using apache-fpm in DDEV.

T3 site config.yaml

```
base: 'https://sample-project.ddev.site/'
```

ddev config.yaml

```
name: sample-project
webserver_type: apache-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
use_dns_when_possible: true
```

that works fine when calling in safari **https://sample-project.ddev.site/**
but when calling in safari **sample-project.ddev.site**  it does not work I get an T3 oops
so I have inserted in .htaccess (equivalent to my hosting server)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

now safari moans too many redirects and I wonder where these redirects come from and why, no redirects in T3 backend are set, no further changes to .htaccess vs the original T3 .htaccess
I was expecting ddev to simply redirect **sample-project.ddev.site**  to **https://sample-project.ddev.site/**

Comment: Not TYPO3 related really. These rules will cause a redirect from `http://sample-project.ddev.site` to `http://sample-project.ddev.site/` then to `http://sample-project.ddev.site//` then to `http://sample-project.ddev.site///` then to `http://sample-project.ddev.site////` and so on without ever coming to TYPO3.

Comment: Why do you use "!off"? Your condition then is: When HTTPS is on, then redirect to HTTPS? This is why it results in too many redirects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please use this redirect. Since ddev-router is terminating HTTPS, it sets X-Forwarded-Proto, but the ddev-webserver (where you are putting the rule) is actually getting the traffic via HTTP.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```