# TYPO3 11.5 - redirect to urls with trailing slash or not

Tags: .htaccess, typo3-11.x

I noticed that TYPO3 11.5 results in a 404 error when the trailing slash is omitted.
In older TYPO3 versions a simple rule in .htaccess could redirect to URLs with trailing slash instead.
When I apply this rule ([TYPO3 - force trailing-slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777804/typo3-force-trailing-slashes)) to version 11.5 the backend would do endless redirects (as it is without trailing slash)

What would be best practice for TYPO3 11.5 ? Should we redirect at all ?

Comment: "the backend would do endless redirects (as it is without trailing slash)" - What specifically is the redirect-loop you are seeing? Not sure what you mean by "as it is without trailing slash"? Presumably the URL in question works correctly when the trailing slash is included manually? I don't see why this would necessarily cause a redirect loop. What URL you are requesting? What other directives do you have in `.htaccess`? Where exactly have you placed this directive in `.htaccess`?

Comment: The URL for the backend ist now: yourdomain.com/typo3/login , where "login" is without trailing slash. But I believe, I have solved my issue by excluding the BE-typo3 folder from my rule. Thanks fort all effort.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, this part in .htaccess seem to solve the issue for me:

```
# add trailing slash for outside typo3 folder if missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(typo3)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I put this part near the end of all default-mod-rewirte code before this default-part:

```
# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
# For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```